# How to handle user 1 with PCI compliance

Tags: security

PCI compliance states there can be no shared accounts. Typically between developers user 1 is shared and utilized for things that require user 1, but that would violate the PCI rules.

Is there a way to prevent the user 1 account from violating PCI rules?

Comment: add more users and make them administrators, that way you don't have to share user 1.

Comment: One possible method is to have separate roles for developers, site administrators, content editors etc. and give your developers the more powerful developer role. Which roles are relevant depends on your particular project and users.

Comment: I didn't realize that you no longer needed UID one for certain things (in D6 this was an issue) https://www.drupal.org/node/947312 the user can be removed and seperate admin accounts with an admin role can do what it does